# dataframe "if" loop changes all lines including those without the character using Pandas and Python 3.7

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, prefix

I am a beginner with Python and Pandas. Please be patience :-)

I am having an issue in which I only want to add a prefix to specific column values that have a coma in it. The dataframe was read from an xlsx file.

The code is:

```
if data['rule.source'].str.contains(',').any():
    print ('there is a ","')
    data['rule.source'] = 'prefixtoline with "," ' + data['rule.source']
else:
    print ('there is no comma and no prefix added')
```

However, the code above adds the prefix to all lines including those without a `","` on it.

I searched the internet for an answer and no luck, could not find anything that would solve my issue

Any guidance would be appreciated!

Comment: Use `data.loc[data["rule.source"].str.contains(","),"rule.source"] = 'prefixtoline with ","'+data.loc[data["rule.source"].str.contains(","),"rule.source"]`.

Comment: That did it, Thanks @HenryYik!!!